# Hasse diagram relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

i am conflicted with my professors solution here because by definition show in red in the picture, the {1} subset of the bottom set is not a subset of the {2,3} subset of the middle far right set. i have my diagram set up so that the set at the top is related to everything else below it and there is only one level of relation.[image]

Comment: It must be a subset of *a* set in the partition, not of *every* set in the partition.  Certainly $\{1\}\subseteq\{1\}$.

Comment: Thank you i got confused by the wording